# the arc length of an ellipse, eccentricity

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

exercise:

The upper arc of the ellipse $x^{2} / a^{2}+y^{2} / b^{2}=1$, with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ is the curve
$$
y=\frac{b}{a} \sqrt{a^{2}-x^{2}}, \quad-a<x<a .
$$
It is often convenient to express properties of the ellipse in terms of $a$, and the eccentricity $e$, defined as
$$
e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}} .
$$
Given $c$ such that $0<c<a$, express the integral for the arc length of the ellipse, from $x=0$ to $x=c$, in terms of $a, e$ and $c$.

Attempt:

In the previous exercise we have defined $\arcsin\,c$ as integral for the arc length of the curve $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ from $x = 0$ to $x = c$, where $0 < c < 1$.
$$\arcsin(c)=\int_0^c\sqrt\frac{1}{1-x^2}\,dx$$

We can write the ellipse equation solved for $$y=\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)(1-e^2)}$$ and following the arc length formula we can write the arc length of the ellipse, from $x = 0$ to $x = c$ $$\int_0^c{\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2e^2}{a^2-x^2}}}\,dx$$ but where is "$c$". I'm not sure this is what the author intended. I guess the result of the previous exercise should have been used here. However, I don't know how to consider it here.

Can anybody help me, please?

P.S. I am familiar with the formulas containing $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ but meanwhile we have not defined them I cant use it.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~mcasquilho/compute/com/,ellips/PerimeterOfEllipse.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182381/finding-out-the-perimeter-of-the-ellipse/4182970#4182970

Comment: thanks for reply but I am interested is there any way avoid using sin and cos or it is the only way. because we haven't defined trigonometric functions yet

Comment: @emilagazade The perimeter of an ellipse usually is an [elliptic Integral of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html), not a trigonometric function. There is no defined special function for the inverse in general. However, there are [elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function)

Comment: @TymaGaidash I appreciate your comment.  but the problem is these elliptic functions defined in terms of trigonometric functions even some sort of "sn" "dn" I am not familiar with them at all. Generally we have not studied trig functions yet.

Comment: book suggests write the integral in terms of $a,c,e$

Comment: You have defined $\pmb{c}$ once as $0\lt \pmb{c} \lt a$ and then as $0\lt \pmb{c} \lt 1$. Which of these two $\pmb{c}$ s do you mean when you asked $Where\space is \space \pmb{c}?$

Comment: @YNK $0\lt \pmb{c} \lt 1$ it is for the previous exercise. it is written above. I guess the result of the first exercise  should be used here but don't know how

Comment: The exercise is to *write out the integral*. There is no requirement for you to actually solve the integral, or write out the arclength as some function of $c$ not defined through integration.

Comment: Yes @PaulSinclair of course I am not going compute the integral but I am confused about the "author suggest-write in terms of c" I think it is not about using c as bound of the integral but as integral expression

Comment: No, they expect that $c$ will be a bound. What you have written (assuming you've applied the arclength formula correctly, I haven't checked) is exactly what they are after.

Comment: thanks a lot @PaulSinclair You have relieved my concerns